# Losing elements in array invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm calling a powershell script thus:

```
function checkUrlOnSites([string[]]$urls) {
    #1
    Write-Verbose $urls.count
    $results=invoke-command -computername $computerName -ea silentlycontinue 
               -ev errRemote -scriptblock ${function:checkUrlOnSite} -args $urls
}


function checkUrlOnSite([string[]]$urls)
{
    #2
    Write-Verbose $urls.count
}
```

The first `Write-Verbose` writes `2` the second writes `1`? what am I missing here? Where's my other string disappearing to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in this way:

```
$results=invoke-command -computername $computerName -ea silentlycontinue `
               -ev errRemote -scriptblock ${function:checkUrlOnSite} -argumentlist (,$urls)
```

You need to force the argument as an array with the comma notation `(,$urls)`

Comment: Looks good. Will just check before accepting, currently busy looking at something else though! :)